# NGINX warn on stop or restart

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, fedora

I'm trying to use NGINX as a reverse proxy on my development workflow. However, whenever I stop or restart the server, I got this warning:

```
nginx: [warn] could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 2048 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
```

I've tried set types_hash_max_size to 2048 and 4096, types_hash_bucket_size to 64 and 128 and server_names_hash_bucket_size to 128. I've tried to put those settings either on http, server and location, with no success.

Here's my config file:

```
http {
  server { 
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;

    server_name localhost;

    location / { 
      proxy_pass http://example.com/;
    }
  }

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;
  types_hash_bucket_size 128;
}

events {}
```

My environment:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 27 (Twenty Seven)
Release:    27
Codename:   TwentySeven

$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.12.1
```

Also, I'm running NGINX this way:

```
$ sudo nginx -p `pwd` -c proxy.conf
```